# A Solid Example of a Column Series, etc., in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I'm looking for a solid explanation / demonstration of a column series in ExtJS. Is there a good resource out there that shows how to use some of the more obscure chart objects (like column series, bar series, Cartesian series, etc.,)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some extensive work with ExtJS but have always found myself using [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) for my charting needs even within ExtJS based applications.
Multiple reasons -

1. Have been using ExtJS + [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) since before Sencha came out with any serious charting widgets.
2. Dexterity/richness of [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) is way higher than the ExtJS charting widgets.

Client side stack comprising  of ExtJS + Ext Direct + [ux.Media.ChartPack](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?32434-ux.Media.ChartPack-2.1.2-%28Fusion-OFC2-amChart%29-released.&highlight=FusionPanel) + [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)  works like a charm for me (and my users).

(I know this does not really answer your question but I guess gives you a different perspective?)